# How to increase the memory availability to the OS without adding more RAM?

Tags: memory

I have a machine with 2 GB RAM fused in the motherboard and no extra memory slots.   Is there any techniques to increase the RAM availability to OS without needing to add more RAM?

My machine is Lenovo Ideapad, windows 8.1, 2GB RAM, Intel Celeron (dual core).

Comment: Why are you trying to allocate more RAM to the OS? With such a massively underpowered machine, most people would be trying to allocate _less_ RAM, so more is available for programs.

Comment: No;  What you what is not possible.

Comment: @Ramhound Don't say nothing is possible! ;-)

Comment: If your system uses a hard drive and not some type of flash storage like an SSD, you'd probably benefit from ReadyBoost, which uses external flash storage such as a USB flash drive or SD card to cache disk accesses which would otherwise be cached in memory on a system with more RAM. This can noticeably improve application start times and system responsiveness.

Comment: @Stackcraft_noob - Except it isn't possible to just add "more" memory to a system without adding hardware, sure he can attempt to reduce the system footprint some, but that will be 200MB at most.  ReadyBoost is one option but it won't do that much in reality, an still, isn't system memory which is what the author wanted.

Comment: What is the model number of the laptop?

Comment: @Burgi, Its a "Lenovo Ideapad Flex 10"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have a USB flash drive you can use ReadyBoost. It doesn't extend your RAM but it loads frequently used files onto the USB stick so that applications will load faster.

http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/turn-readyboost-on-off-storage-device

Comment: ReadyBoost will not increase system memory.  However, it can speed up disk access on low memory systems.